# Pointer and integer representation in memory

Tags: c, pointers, binary, endianness

I'm learning about pointer in c and i have this program i'm taken from some book as an example.

```
void print_bytes(void *start, size_t size);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int val = 42;
    print_bytes(&val ,sizeof(val));

    return 0;
}

void print_bytes(void *start, size_t size)
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
         printf("%02X ", *((unsigned char *)start + i));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to print the value of each bytes in `hexadecimal` format pointed to by `start pointer`    variable in the function print_bytes.

As far as i know when an `integers` variables are stored in memory, the variables are stored in binary format.

This is my analysis if i run the code :
Suppose the sizeof an integer variable is `4 bytes (32 bits)`  then 
if the memory hold an integer value 42 then the representation in memory is :

42 only fit in first 8 bit representation of bytes in memory.

binary : `00000000` `00000000` `00000000` `00101010`

so if i run the code i got `2A`. So far the output is correct.

if the memory hold an integer value larger than 42, suppose 3000 (that is definitely require more than a single bytes to represent the value in binary in memory) then the representation in memory is :

binary : `00000000 00000000 00001011 10111000`

if i run the code i got 'B8 0B 00 00' that seems to me wrong insead of `BB 80 00 00`.

Please someone explain what's wrong, I'm tryting to solve this for hours but no clue.

Thank you before. I'll appreciate every answers and try to learn from them.

Comment: Please read this about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: You made an oversight in the first example using `42`. The program did not just print `2A` as you say, it printed `2A 00 00 00`. That is, the least significant byte first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short endianness doesn't apply to bits only bytes.

Whatever platform you're on will behave as though the low bits are on the right. You can tell this because shift right (`>>`) will always reduce a value never increase it.

Your platform is little-endian. So the binary value `00000000 00000000 00001011 10111000` (written in convention most-significant digit first format) is stored as `10111000 00001011 00000000 00000000`.

Notice the bits aren't reversed only the bytes. Going through turning that into hex gives us:

```
10111000 00001011 00000000 00000000
B   8    0   B    0   0    0   0
```

Footnote: How bits are physically stored is undefined. We are talking about how the computers memory is logically represented to you in C. Not how the physical components are arranged.